# Firefox not reachable for long running : selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am instantiating Firefox Browser from a java program using selenium.
For a long running Firefox(say 6 hrs), my program is exiting with the below error message

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '2.35.0', revision: '8df0c6bedf70ff9f22c647788f9fe9c8d22210e2', time: '2013-08-17 12:46:41'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'i386', os.version: '2.6.32.59-0.3-default', java.version: '1.6.0_23'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
```

But If I `grep` for firefox process (`ps -ef|grep firefox`) Firefox instance is still running.

Comment: Just curious, why would you need to run webdriver instance for that long?

Comment: Please update your answer here or select any answer from below as correct and close the question so that other can get the solution you have found.

Answer (score 0):

When you are triggering a run, first clear the history and cache memory which will definitely help you..

Answer (score 0):

Its a common issue you will face with Firefox below are the option that you can take to resolve it.

1. Every 1 hour create new Firefox drive and close previous.
2. If you run Firefox in Windows machine running in Safe mode with Networking this error does not come.
3. My favorite, use chrome browser i.e. Chrome driver.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is problem related to firefox cache .

Remember this point:

1. Always close browser when you run a script on firefox, means 
     use `close()` method.
2. Clean the Temporary files in 2- 3 hours so it speed up your 
     script execution.
3. You can also use other different browsers.

Comment: 3 isn't a solution. 2 also seems irrelevant when user execute for few hours. and is 1 a solution for running selenium test?